# Lost when trying to get good time series prediction results (regression problem) even after trying many things

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, time-series, regression

I'm not able to get good results after a long time testing when using TensorFlow to predict time series data (regression problem). I don't know if the problem is with the data (little quantity and/or low quality) or with the model (or if there is a problem with both) (although I have tried several and tested various combinations of hyperparameters). I'm really tired and I don't know what else to do. What would you do if you were in my place? Where could I find someone who can help me with this problem? Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Hi @Marco, welcome to the site. It's difficult to tell you anything without more specific information. Nevertheless, I would suggest starting with the simplest model that could work and then build up from there. Also, you may try time series approaches that are known to work mostly out of the box, like [Prophet](https://github.com/facebook/prophet) or [auto-ARIMA](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima)